# Negating a quantified formula NOR

Tags: predicate-logic

I want to negate the following sentence:

```
All redheaded persons in the room have a pet , that either cat or dog is
```

I must not negate the quantifier.

Comment: Your last statement: Do you mean that instead of "not all redheaded persons....", you need to exchange it with "exists a redheaded person (who fails to satisfy the rest of the statement?  That's simply a matter of equivalence.  "not all x satisfy P(x)" is equivalent to  "exists x such that it isn't the case that P(x).

Comment: I won't assist you on any more questions you post, SHristoskov, until you include in your posts, your own attempts to address the question you intend to post here.  There isn't even a proper question asked in your post!  "I want (you guys) to negate the following sentence:"  "I must not negate the quantifier" i.e.(you guys provide a negation that doesn't start with "not all ...").  In turn, I want that askers take time, apply effort and to make an attempt, or two, or three!, before asking questions here.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Negating a quantified formula](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2248446/negating-a-quantified-formula)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The negation of this sentence can be kind of nuanced, especially for a nonnative English speaker (which I assume you are because of the misplaced verb in the question). I'm assuming you want the negation of the sentence,

> All redheaded persons in the room have a pet that is either a cat or a dog.

This is kind of tricky because there is an implied 'and' in the sentence. With the 'and' included, it should be,

> All redheaded persons in the room have a pet **AND** that pet is either a cat or a dog.

So the negation of this sentence would be,

There exists a redheaded person in the room who has no pet or has a pet which is not a cat or dog.

Comment: No, The outermost quantifier ($\forall$) is a strong signal that the main connective for the sentence is implication.   All redheaded persons in the room have a pet that is either a cat or dog" translates to "For all persons $a$ (**If** ($a$ is a redhead and is in the room), **then** ($a$ has a pet *and* this pet is either a cat or a dog.))"

Comment: But I think your natural language version of its negation is just fine, awright96.

Comment: I think your interpretation is equally as valid as my own, but 'There exists a redheaded person in the room who has no pet or has a pet which is not a cat or dog' is still a valid negation of your interpretation.

Comment: Precisely; that's a phenomenon that's bound to occur when trying to represent logic using natural language, and the other way around!

Comment: I just countered the downvote you received, awright96. It's too bad the downvoter never expressed why s/he downvoted your post.